# Invoke process activity not logging any error in log file

Tags: android-activity, workflow

I am trying to use Invoke process to invoke an executable from my windows workflow in my TFS 2010 build.
But when I am looking at the log file it is not logging any error.
I did use WriteBuildMessage and WriteBuildwarning inside my invoke process activity.
I also set the filename,workingdirectory etc in activity.

Can someone please point out why it is not logging?

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:
[image]

In this case you have to ensure that `Message` are set as follows:
[image]

[image]

With those parameters set as depicted, I catch what you seem to be after.

Furthermore, you can check in the `Properties` of your `InvokeProcess`: 
Set the `Result` into a string-variable and then set in a subsequent `WriteBuildMessage` this string-variable to be the `Message`. This way, you 'll additionally catch the return of your invoked process.

**EDIT**
Another common thing that you 've possibly overlooked is the `BuildMessageImportance`: if it is not set as `High`, messages do NOT appear under default Logging Verbosity (= `Normal`). See [here](http://books.google.gr/books?id=9d7JUTMpZDYC&pg=PA400&lpg=PA400&dq=tfs%20writebuildmessage%20verbosity&source=bl&ots=b-vw8QVMgs&sig=huOw-i-J4winN05CX7N-iEXZatY&hl=el&ei=XoXYTt3_Lciq-Abiw6CxDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg) for some background.

Comment: Also, make sure that you're checking the result (i.e. using an `If` statement) *inside* the `Agent Scope`, it took me a long time to work out why our errors weren't being caught...  Often the simple things!

Comment: @pantelif: I have double checked what you mentioned above.I have initialized exitcode as a variable in results part.But still it is not logging the error.

Comment: @Daniel: I didn't get, can you elaborate little more about it.

Comment: Man, that BuildMessageImportance has been killing me for some time.  Thanks! +1

Answer (score 3):

In your `Invoke Process`, you want to set the `Result` property to update a variable (returns an Int, so lets call it `ExitCode`), under your `Invoke Process` (but still in the `Agent Scope`) you can drop in an `If`, so you can set the condition of this to `ExitCode <> 0` and do whatever you like on a failure (such as failing the build).

Also, as a note, if your `WriteBuildMessage` is not showing anything in your log, you need to set the `Importance` to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.High`, anything lower and it wont show in the Normal logging level.